# How to use NHibernate to process multiple resultsets/SYS_REFCURSOR from Oracle stored procedure

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, stored-procedures, resultset, sys-refcursor

I can get NHibernate (v2) to return and process a single SYS_REFCURSOR that contains my single resultset. Is it possible for multiple resultsets/SYS_REFCURSOR's in NHibernate? What would be the syntax of the .hbm.xml file to map multiple resultsets from the SYS_REFCURSOR's?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly sure the answer is no, this isn't possible. You have two options to work around this: use a MultiQuery against two stored procs to batch the calls or 2) use the database connection and ADO.NET.

Comment: MultiQuery allows you to send multiple SQL statements in a single batch. See http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-16-improving/1nr4enxv3dpeq/19#16%282E%297%282E%29%28C2%29%28A0%29Multi_Query.